# Is it possible to disable "list file" feature of 7-zip?

Tags: 7-zip, 7za

We need to 7zip files whose filename starts with "@", but the following command would fail:

7za a -tzip -- a.zip @abc.com

because 7zip has "list file" feature (https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/syntax.htm), so that the above command would trigger 7zip to look for a file "abc.com" instead of "@abc.com" which we hope to zip.

Is there a way to disable this feature of 7zip?  If not what's the best way around?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same file can be specified *with a path* so that the entire parameter no longer starts with a `@` even if the name still does. Similar to "how to remove a file that starts with a `-`":

```
7za a -tzip -- a.zip ./@abc.com
```

(`.` is the path for the current directory. You can probably also specify the full path, e.g. using `$PWD` or `%CD%`, as 7zip will still automatically strip it away when building the archive.)

Comment: Thanks!  That should work well.